# How can I return an empty IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Given the following code and the suggestions given [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225760/i-seem-to-have-fallen-into-some-massive-massive-trouble-with-nullreferenceexcept), I've decided to modify this original method and ask if there are any values in the `IEnumarable` return it, if not return an `IEnumerable` with no values.

Here is the method:

```
public IEnumerable<Friend> FindFriends()
{
    //Many thanks to Rex-M for his help with this one.
    //https://stackoverflow.com/users/67/rex-m

    return doc.Descendants("user").Select(user => new Friend
    {
        ID = user.Element("id").Value,
        Name = user.Element("name").Value,
        URL = user.Element("url").Value,
        Photo = user.Element("photo").Value
    });
}
```

Since everything is inside the return statement, I don't know how I could do this. Would something like this work?

```
public IEnumerable<Friend> FindFriends()
{
    //Many thanks to Rex-M for his help with this one.
    //https://stackoverflow.com/users/67/rex-m
    if (userExists)
    {
        return doc.Descendants("user").Select(user => new Friend
        {
            ID = user.Element("id").Value,
            Name = user.Element("name").Value,
            URL = user.Element("url").Value,
            Photo = user.Element("photo").Value
        });
    }
    else
    { 
        return new IEnumerable<Friend>();
    }
}
```

The above method doesn't work, and in fact it's not supposed to; I just feel it illustrates my intentions. *I feel I should specify that the code doesn't work because you can't create an instance of an abstract class.*

Here is the calling code, I don't want it to receive a null `IEnumerable` at any time:

```
private void SetUserFriends(IEnumerable<Friend> list)
{
    int x = 40;
    int y = 3;

    foreach (Friend friend in list)
    {
        FriendControl control = new FriendControl();
        control.ID = friend.ID;
        control.URL = friend.URL;
        control.SetID(friend.ID);
        control.SetName(friend.Name);
        control.SetImage(friend.Photo);

        control.Location = new Point(x, y);
        panel2.Controls.Add(control);

        y = y + control.Height + 4;
    } 
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Looking at the code here you should be using yield return and yield break.

Answer (score 675, accepted):

You can use `list ?? Enumerable.Empty<Friend>()`, or have `FindFriends` return `Enumerable.Empty<Friend>()`

This can be found under the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Would it change things if he returned, say, `new List<Friend>()` since it will be cast to `IEnumerable<Friend>` when returned from that method?

Comment: `new List<Friend>()` is a more expensive operation because it would create an instance of a list (and allocate memory for it in the process)

Comment: Starting in 2015 (.NET Framework 4.6) you can also use `Array.Empty<Friend>()` which has a bit fewer characters to type (in `System` namespace, not `System.Linq`).

Answer (score 195):

You could return [`Enumerable.Empty<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx).

Answer (score 120):

As for me, most elegant way is `yield break`

Comment: But that's if you use yield return and such, isn't it?

Comment: +1 as his code correctly should use yield for the way he's working with IEnumerable

Comment: Pardon my ignorance on the subject, but could you please illustrate how to use yield break in this context? I've seen examples only in for loops but that doesn't paint a clear picture for me.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example. Really is the most elegant way of doing it I would agree. :)

Comment: Edit got rejected in peer review, so here's the example I was talking about @Pyritie - the formatting gets messed up though, so I added it to http://pastebin.com/X9Z49Vq1 as well:
`public IEnumerable<Friend> FindFriends()
{
  if(!userExists) yield break;

  foreach(var descendant in doc.Descendants("user").Select(user => new Friend
    {
        ID = user.Element("id").Value,
        Name = user.Element("name").Value,
        URL = user.Element("url").Value,
        Photo = user.Element("photo").Value
    }))
  {
    yield return descendant;
  }
}`

Comment: I know that I'm several years late, but I'm wondering if someone would comment on why using a yield statement is the "correct" way. It certainly doesn't appear "most elegant" to me since you would have to add a foreach statement just to be able to use the yield.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

That's of course only a matter of personal preference, but I'd write this function using yield return:

```
public IEnumerable<Friend> FindFriends()
{
    //Many thanks to Rex-M for his help with this one.
    //http://stackoverflow.com/users/67/rex-m
    if (userExists)
    {
        foreach(var user in doc.Descendants("user"))
        {
            yield return new Friend
                {
                    ID = user.Element("id").Value,
                    Name = user.Element("name").Value,
                    URL = user.Element("url").Value,
                    Photo = user.Element("photo").Value
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way would be

```
 return new Friend[0];
```

The requirements of the return are merely that the method return an object which implements `IEnumerable<Friend>`.  The fact that under different circumstances you return two different kinds of objects is irrelevant, as long as both implement IEnumerable.

Comment: Enumerable.Empty<T> actually returns an empty array of T (T[0]), with the advantage that the same empty array is reused. Note that this approach is not ideal for non-empty arrays, because the elements can be modified (however an array can't be resized, resizing involves creating a new instance).

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<Friend> FindFriends()
{
    return userExists ? doc.Descendants("user").Select(user => new Friend
        {
            ID = user.Element("id").Value,
            Name = user.Element("name").Value,
            URL = user.Element("url").Value,
            Photo = user.Element("photo").Value
        }): new List<Friend>();
}
```

Comment: Using List for returning an empty Enumerable is wasting. Array.Empty<T>() or Enumerable.Empty<T>() are the most resource sparing solutions.
In fact Enumerable.Empty<T>() itself returns an empty array, see: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs