# Is there an "Empty List" singleton in C#?

Tags: c#, singleton, ienumerable, empty-list

In C# I use LINQ and IEnumerable a good bit. And all is well-and-good (or at least mostly so).

However, in many cases I find myself that I need an empty `IEnumerable<X>` as a default. That is, I would like

```
for (var x in xs) { ... }
```

to work without needing a null-check. Now this is what I currently do, depending upon the larger context:

```
var xs = f() ?? new X[0];              // when xs is assigned, sometimes
for (var x in xs ?? new X[0]) { ... }  // inline, sometimes
```

Now, while the above is *perfectly fine for me* -- that is, if there is any "extra overhead" with creating the array object I *just don't care* -- I was wondering:

*Is there "empty immutable IEnumerable/IList" singleton in C#/.NET?* (And, even if not, is there a "better" way to handle the case described above?)

Java has [`Collections.EMPTY_LIST`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#EMPTY_LIST) immutable singleton -- "well-typed" via [`Collections.emptyList<T>()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) -- which serves this purpose, although I am not sure if a similar concept could even work in C# because generics are handled differently.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, darn :) This is what I get for focusing on List/IList and not Enumerable/IEnumerable, thanks all -- votes all around.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229698/how-can-i-return-an-empty-ienumerable

Comment: `public static class Array<T> { public static readonly T[] Empty = new T[0]; }` and it can be called like: `Array<string>.Empty`. I asked about it [here in CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/20417/17039).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You are looking for [`Enumerable.Empty<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx).

In other news the Java empty list sucks because the List interface exposes methods for adding elements to the list which throw exceptions.

Comment: That's a very valid point! Perhaps it warrants a new SO question?

Comment: You were a few seconds slow and no documentation link _*finger shake*_ ;-) But the accept for expanding upon svicks comment.

Comment: Also the other guys got more upvotes so we're even:)

I would post a question but I'm going to bed right now and I won't be able to follow the question. Why not post it yourself?

Comment: Because a class method may need to return a `List` (a collection that can be accessed by index). Those `List` can be readonly. And sometime you need to return such a readonly `List` with zero element in it. Thus, the `Collections.emptyList()` method. You can't just return an empty Iterable because an implemented interface specify that the method return a list. The big problem is that their is no ImmutableList interface that you can return. The same problem exist in .NET : any `IList` may well be readonly.

Comment: On a side note, every array is a IList<correspondingType> in C#, and this will throw when you try to add new items as well.

Comment: function shouldIUseList(readOnlyMethodsINeed){ return (setOfListMethods() - setOfIterableMethods()).containsAny(readOnlyMethodsINeed); }

Comment: Throwing exceptions vs read-only interface ~= getting error at runtime vs getting it at compile-time. I would definitely prefer Java spec to define a read-only interface for lists, but that's unfortunately not the case.

Comment: To whom it may concern: Very often, the reason for wanting some kind of list (rather than `IEnumerable<T>`) is its property of being materialized (no deferred execution) and having a known `Count`. In this case, we should use `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. If indexed access is also required, there is `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Answer (score 57):

[`Enumerable.Empty<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx) is exactly that.

Comment: Well, not *exactly*. :) Since a "list" was asked for, `Array.Empty<T>()` is more accurate, as it is an `IList<T>`. It has the happy benefit of also satisfying `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Of course, where an `IEnumerable<T>` *does* suffice, `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` fits perfectly.

Comment: @Timo this question, and many of the answers including this one, were written roughly 3 years before `Array.Empty<T>` was made available. :) In any case, the title notwithstanding, the question makes it explicitly clear that an `IEnumerable<T>` is good for the purpose.

Answer (score 23):

In your original example you use an empty array to provide an empty enumerable. While using `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` is perfectly right, there might other cases: if you *have to use* an array (or the `IList<T>` interface), you can use the method

```
System.Array.Empty<T>()
```

which helps you to avoid unnecessary allocations.

Notes / References:

- the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.empty?view=netframework-4.7#System_Array_Empty__1) does not mention that this method allocates the empty array only once for each type
- [roslyn analyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/master/src/Microsoft.NetCore.Analyzers/Microsoft.NetCore.Analyzers.md) recommend this method with the warning *CA1825: Avoid zero-length array allocations*
- Microsoft [reference implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,765d2f7e4e3f8521)
- [.NET Core implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/mscorlib/src/System/Array.cs)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the documentation is out of line with roslyn analyzers.  Did you ever open an issue on GitHub to correct that?

Answer (score 20):

I think you're looking for [`Enumerable.Empty<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx).

Empty list singleton doesn't make that much sense, because lists are often mutable.

Answer (score 11):

I think adding an extension method is a clean alternative thanks to their ability to handle nulls - something like:

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
  {
    return list ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
  }

  foreach(var x in xs.EmptyIfNull())
  {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` with lists has a drawback. If you hand `Enumerable.Empty<T>` into the list constructor then an array of size 4 is allocated. But if you hand an empty `Collection` into the list constructor then no allocation occurs. So if you use this solution throughout your code then most likely one of the `IEnumerable`s will be used to construct a list, resulting in unnecessary allocations.

Comment: why would you ever pass `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` into a constructor for a `List<T>`?  That makes no sense to me.  The point of `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` is to avoid having to initialize empty `List<T>` instances where you need an empty and non-null instance.

Comment: Since this answer is newer than 2015, it could mention `Array.Empty<T>()` which came with .NET Framework 4.6 from 2015. This is useful if you need an empty (preallocated and immutable) instance of compile-time type `T[]`, `IReadOnlyList<T>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft implemented `Any()' like this ([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs))

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (e.MoveNext()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want to save a call on the call stack, instead of writing an extension method that calls `!Any()`, just rewrite make these three changes:

```
public static bool IsEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) //first change (name)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (e.MoveNext()) return false; //second change
    }
    return true; //third change
}
```